# how do i pass input empty value from scanner to zero double value in java?

Tags: java

I have three inputs from scanner in my java application. so I need to enter all values as double values. my scenario is if I didn't enter any number in run environment, consider zero as a default value of the number.
So if I didn't input any values for each of three numbers or all of them, the default value should be zero. but hen I press enter without any input, I will receive the following error.

What id the problem?

```java
import java.util.*;

public class JavaApplication1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double i;
        String is;
        double j;
        String js;
        double k;
        String ks;
        System.out.println("Pleas Enter Input(s)\n");
        try (Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            is = scn.nextLine();
            js = scn.nextLine();
            ks = scn.nextLine();
            i = Double.valueOf(is);
            j = Double.parseDouble(js);
            k = Double.parseDouble(ks);
        }
        SimpleCalculator sc;
        sc = new SimpleCalculator(i, j, k);
        sc.PrintInfo();
    }
}
```

ERROR:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
    at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.base/java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:549)
    at JavaApplication1.main(JavaApplication1.java:19)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create method for this and use it Example:

```
private double parseDouble(String number) {
    if (number == null || number.isEmpty()) {
        return 0.0;
    }

    return Double.parseDouble(number);
}

double test = parseDouble(""); // 0.0
```